# Gradle v4.3.1 for android studio 2.3.3

Tags: android, gradle

I'm using Android Studio 2.3.3, Gradle latest release V4.3.1 is not fixing my "re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)" problem what should i do?

Comment: I followed each and every step where we extract Gradle versions and go to settings and change things BUT still its not working!

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade the Android Studio to 3.0.0 to use gradle-4.1-all.zip

Once upgrade if you want to use the Android Studio 2.3.3 then

1. go to "File->Setting->Build,Execution,deployment->Gradle"
2. Select "Use local gradle distribution" and select the gradle path.

Mostly gradle will be present in C:\Users\'your system user name'\.gradle